# How to make git alert me about undesired files?

Tags: git

#### Little bit of context first

So, my project is using `yarn` for package management instead of `npm`. However we recently noticed a weird `package-lock.json` that made it to the `master` branch without anyone noticing during code reviews.

To avoid it from happening again we could just add `package-lock.json` to `.gitignore`, but I'm sure someone will eventually incorrectly use `npm` again and might end up getting incorrect dependencies due to the non-versioned--probably out of date--`package-lock.json` being there. So I had the idea to somehow make git warn when it detects the existence of the undesired `package-lock.json` file.

#### Finally the question

How can I configure git to detect the existence of certain file(s) and warn me about them?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure a [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_committing_workflow_hooks) to warn you if you try to commit the file again. It would need to be setup for each person working on the repo though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do indeed want to ignore the `package-lock.json` file, since it's not part of your project and you don't want someone to check it in accidentally. That's exactly the scenario `.gitignore` was created for.

In that case, Git won't provide any option to warn about its presence or absence, since you'll have told it to ignore the file. Even if you did check it in (which is the other option, but not the right one here), Git wouldn't warn you about it existing, because that's not a feature it has.

You can, however, use `git clean` to remove ignored files such as your `package-lock.json` if there's a problem, but be aware that it can also remove untracked files, so you need to use it carefully (or test with `-n` before running). You could also make a part of your development build step warn about the file's existence (or just delete it) if that's a thing you want to do. But there isn't any native functionality in Git to do what you want.